# Trouble combining IF statements in formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to create one formula that will do this: If <=10, then take 50% of the amount, if >10, then the lower of 5 or 25% of the amount.

I converted the second statement to Excel by saying if >20, then 25%, otherwise 5.

Is there any way to combine these two statements?

```
=ROUNDUP((IF(E33<=10,E33*0.5,0)),0)
=ROUNDUP((IF(E33>20,E33*0.25,5)),0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

`=IF(A1<=10,A1*0.5,IF(A1>10,MIN(5,A1*0.25),""))`

Basically, if A1 <= 10, then calculate 50% of A. Else, if A1 > 10, take the minimum of 5 and 25% of A1.

Comment: Nice job. You can actually do away with the second `IF` because `A1>10` is the else case for the first condition.

Comment: You're right Excellll, the second if is redundant. More efficient: `=IF(A1<=10,A1*0.5,MIN(5,A1*0.25))`